# PyQGIS: Create feature on Layer A when splitting Layer B

Tags: pyqgis

I have a CompoundcurveZ Layer A with the fields `fk_to`, `fk_from`, `elev_to` and `elev_from`. The foreign keys reference a PointZ Layer B. I am now trying to setup a python action on Layer A that uses `qgis.utils.iface.actionSplitFeatures()` to create a new feature on Layer B and altering the `fk_*` and `elev_*` on Layer A, but I don't know how to access the split point. So far I have the following code:

```
a_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('A')
b_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('B')
b_pkey= b_lyr.fieldNameIndex('obj_id')
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 
caps_b = wn_lyr.dataProvider().capabilities()
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    a_lyr.startEditing()
    b_lyr.startEditing()
    qgis.utils.iface.actionSplitFeatures().trigger()
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(re_lyr)
    for a_feat in /*split feature in Layer A*/:
        b_feat = QgsFeature(b_lyr.fields());
        b_feat_pkey = b_feat.attributes()[b_pkey]; -- does QgsFeature evaluate default values?
        split_pt = QgsPoint(/*add coordinates of split point*/);
        b_feat.setGeometry(split_pt);
        b_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat]);
        a_feat_end = /*Access split feature where b_feat is end point*/
        a_feat_start = /*Access split feature where b_feat is start point*/
        a_feat_end['fk_to'] = b_feat_pkey;
        a_feat_start['fk_from'] = b_feat_pkey;
        a_feat_end['elev_to'] = split_pt.z();
        a_feat_start['elev_from'] = split_pt.z();
        a_lyr.updatefeature(a_feat_end);
        a_lyr.updatefeature(a_feat_start);
        a_lyr.commit();
        b_lyr.commit();
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

How can I access the the split coordinates and the split features?